# OpenLayers TextStyle background fill only uses one color at a time when rendering

Tags: javascript, openlayers

For my vector tile layer, I have several Point geometry features with text. I'm setting the text style's background fill property for these features to different colors based on the text:

```
if(label === "blue")
{
    textStyle.setBackgroundFill(new Fill({ color: "blue" }));
}
else
{
    textStyle.setBackgroundFill(new Fill({ color: "red" }));
}
```

This works when only a single type of label is rendered and, therefore, only one background fill color is used:

[image]

However, whenever I have different types of labels (meaning multiple colors for the background fills) it only applies one of the colours to the all the features:

[image]

Notice that the labels that were once red (and should still be red) are now blue. The weird thing is, this will change if I pan the map a little:

[image]

The styles for the features are set when the feature is created in the `tileLoadFunction` for the custom source I'm using:

```
tileLoadFunction = (tile, url) =>
{
    //retrieve the labels using XHR request
    ...

    var labelPoint = new Point(Projection.fromLonLat([labels[i].x, labels[i].y]));
    var label = new Feature();

    //set the text style for this feature
    label.setStyle(_this.getLabelVectorFeatureStyle(tile.getTileCoord()[0], labels[i].type, labels[i].label, labels[i].angle));

    label.setGeometry(labelPoint);

    features.push(label);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is your `getLabelVectorFeatureStyle` function reusing style objects?  It might be better set the zoom as a feature property then use a more conventional layer style function which renders immediately and allows you to reuse styles..

Comment: No, `getLabelVectorFeatureStyle` creates and returns a new Style object each time its called. Initially, I was attaching a style function to the VectorTileLayer's `style` property, which in turn called the `getLabelVectorFeatureStyle` method, passing in the properties added to the feature during creation. But that did the same thing happening above so I changed it to the above code instead, but that didn't work either, but layer styling was initially done through a style function.

Comment: Also, note that it is only the background fill property thats broken, the font, text and rotation style properties all work fine.

Comment: It's working as expected here.  Even numbers red, odd numbers blue. https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-dq6it

Comment: But it looks like there is a bug when declutter is used  https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-cox1t

Comment: Ah okay cool, I see you've submitted an issue on Github for (https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10949), thanks.